# Infinitely running broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my project, I have a database containing reminders. I want to compare the date and time stored on database with current date and time and give an alarm. I've used a Broadcast receiver for this. The problem I'm facing is that the receiver is running infinitely and is not allowing the activity to come on the screen. Also, I've checked if the date and time matches in an if condition and called the receiver only if it matches. It's entering the condition and starting the receiver even if the condition is false. Here's my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Code for retrieving values from database, comparing values and starting receiver:

```
    public class DisplayReminderList extends Activity {

ListView lv;
Intent intent;
public MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_reminder_list);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.when_display_listview_today);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    SQLiteDatabase database = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext())
            .getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select title from Reminder", null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        System.out.println("Data : " + c.getString(0));
        adapter.add(c.getString(0));
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    c.close();

    Cursor c1 = database.rawQuery(
            "select title,reminderdate,remindertime from Reminder", null);
    Calendar cal;
    String when_reminder_date, when_reminder_time, d, t, when_reminder_title;
    c1.moveToFirst();
    while (!c1.isAfterLast()) {
        when_reminder_title = c1.getString(0);
        d = c1.getString(1);
        t = c1.getString(2);
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        when_reminder_date = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "-"
                + String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + "-"
                + String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        when_reminder_time = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));

        System.out.println("when_reminder_date =" + when_reminder_date
                + "  db date=" + d + " when_reminder_time="
                + when_reminder_time + " dbtime=" + t);

        if (when_reminder_date == d && t == when_reminder_time) {
            System.out.println("Inside if condition");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("when_reminder_title", when_reminder_title);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);
            c1.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    c1.close();
    database.close();

}

public void playSound(Context context, Uri alert) {
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("OOPS");
    }
}

public Uri getAlarmUri() {
    Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alert == null) {
        alert = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (alert == null) {
            alert = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        }
    }
    return alert;
}

public void addreminder_method(View v) {
    intent = new Intent(this, EnterWhenReminder.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Code for broadcast receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmActivityWhen m = new AlarmActivityWhen();
    String title=intent.getStringExtra("when_reminder_title");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("when_reminder_title", title);
    context.startActivity(i);

    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    m.playSound(context, m.getAlarmUri());

}}
```

Activity called by Broadcast Receiver:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class AlertActivity extends Activity {
    TextView t;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    String title=i.getStringExtra("when_reminder_title");
    t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    t.setText(title);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_alert, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

Update:

I moved c1.movetonext() outside the if block. Now it is not running infinitely like it was earlier. Thank you. But I need it to run continuously in the background and check if the time to give the alarm has arrived. Where should I put the code for the pending intent so that this happens?

Comment: How would you know that your Broadcast receiver runs infinitely, and how you have defined Broadcast receiver in manifest file. Put a Log in Broadcast Receiver and check in logcat is you broadcast reciever runs infinitely?

Comment: make sure `c1.moveToNext();` is running in each iteration of while loop i think it should not be inside of `if()` block.

Comment: You should know String comparison in java using `=` operator should not be done. There is an overloaded method `equals()` which should be used. `when_reminder_date == d` this is a wrong way, use this `when_reminder_date.equals(d)`